# hacer que un textbox solo permita ingresar hasta 9 números luego de eso no deje escribir mas?

Tags: php

tengo 2 textbox uno que ingresa hasta 8 caracteres y el otro a 9 los 2 solo permiten escribir números pero pueden escribir todos los números que quieran los que quiero hacer es que cuando llegue a 8 ya no deje escribir mas como lo hago?
y como puedo hacer que al escribir en la caja de texto de 9 caracteres se ponga este formato 1-1111-1111? gracias de ante mano por la ayuda

```html
mis cajas:


<input type="text" name="cedula" required id="cedula" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return valida(event)" placeholder="ingrese la cédula...">
 
 </div>
 <br><br>
 <div class="col-md-12">
<input type="text" name="telefono" required id="telefono" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return valida(event)" placeholder="Teléfono...">
```

```js
el script para validar los campos:
<script>

function valida(e){
    tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    //Tecla de retroceso para borrar, siempre la permite
    if (tecla==8){
        return true;
    }
        
    // Patron de entrada, en este caso solo acepta numeros
    patron =/[0-9]/;
    
    tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
    return patron.test(tecla_final);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

De esta manera puedes limitar los input

```
<input type="text" name="cedula" min="1" max="9" id="numero">

    var input=  document.getElementById('numero');
input.addEventListener('input',function(){
  if (this.value.length > 9) 
     this.value = this.value.slice(0,12); 
})
```

Comment: lo he añadido pero sigo pudiendo ingresar 1234567899999

Comment: y  mes gustaría que solo me deje escribir por ejemplo 222222222 y al escribir el numero que sigue osea 10 no me deje escribir nada mas

Comment: Ingresa el javascript

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas para limitar el ingreso de carácteres en un input es **[maxlength](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp)**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#telefono").keyup(function(){
      var le = $(this).val().length;
      switch(le){
        case 1:
          $(this).val($(this).val() + "-");
          break;
        case 6:
          $(this).val($(this).val() + "-");
          break;
      }
    });
})

function valida(e){
    tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    //Tecla de retroceso para borrar, siempre la permite
    if (tecla==8){
        return true;
    }
        
    // Patron de entrada, en este caso solo acepta numeros
    patron =/[0-9]/;
    
    tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
    return patron.test(tecla_final);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="telefono" required id="telefono" maxlength="11" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return valida(event)" placeholder="Teléfono...">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

En cuanto al formato que pides (1-1111-1111), ten en cuenta que **sólo dejas ingresar números en el input**, y que al incluirles los guiones, además de no ser números aumentarías el `length` a 11.

Te deje una solución aunque personalmente no me convence mucho, aunque cumple lo que solicitas. Algún colega de mayor experiencia en Javascript podrías mejorarla, así que pendiente a eso!

**PD: Para que funcione debes utilizar JQuery**

Comment: perfecto esto era lo que necesitaba maxlength="9" muchas gracias, ahora como puedo hacer que al escribir el primer numero luego de ese numero me ponga un guion y luego ponga el guion despues de 4 numeros?

Comment: algo asi 1-1111-1111 ?

Comment: si  pero eso no seria problema porque en la función de solo números le agrego el guion y le aumento el length pero como puedo hacer que agregue eso?

Comment: @JEFFmeza Editada! Ojo al comentario que específique. Nos cuentas como te va

Answer (score 0):

Debes asignarle el tipo si quieres hacerlo solo con html el lo toma por defecto

```
<input type="number" name="dni" min="1" max="9" id="tuid">
```

o puedes realizarlo con maxlength ya que el limita automaticamente

```
<input type="number" name="dni" maxlength="11" id="tuid">
```

para lo que comentas puedes usar lo siguiente. solo debes adaptarlo a lo que necesitas que serian 2 - en sitios definidos. https://gist.github.com/rotvulpix/69a24cc199a4253d058c

```js
function checkRut(rut) {
    // Despejar Puntos
    var valor = rut.value.replace('.','');
    // Despejar Guión
    valor = valor.replace('-','');
    
    // Aislar Cuerpo y Dígito Verificador
    cuerpo = valor.slice(0,-1);
    dv = valor.slice(-1).toUpperCase();
    
    // Formatear RUN
    rut.value = cuerpo + '-'+ dv
    
    // Si no cumple con el mínimo ej. (n.nnn.nnn)
    if(cuerpo.length < 7) { rut.setCustomValidity("RUT Incompleto"); return false;}
    
    // Calcular Dígito Verificador
    suma = 0;
    multiplo = 2;
    
    // Para cada dígito del Cuerpo
    for(i=1;i<=cuerpo.length;i++) {
    
        // Obtener su Producto con el Múltiplo Correspondiente
        index = multiplo * valor.charAt(cuerpo.length - i);
        
        // Sumar al Contador General
        suma = suma + index;
        
        // Consolidar Múltiplo dentro del rango [2,7]
        if(multiplo < 7) { multiplo = multiplo + 1; } else { multiplo = 2; }
  
    }
    
    // Calcular Dígito Verificador en base al Módulo 11
    dvEsperado = 11 - (suma % 11);
    
    // Casos Especiales (0 y K)
    dv = (dv == 'K')?10:dv;
    dv = (dv == 0)?11:dv;
    
    // Validar que el Cuerpo coincide con su Dígito Verificador
    if(dvEsperado != dv) { rut.setCustomValidity("RUT Inválido"); return false; }
    
    // Si todo sale bien, eliminar errores (decretar que es válido)
    rut.setCustomValidity('');
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Validador de RUT HTML5</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="rut" name="rut" required oninput="checkRut(this)" placeholder="Ingrese RUT">
        <button type="submit">Validar RUT y Enviar Form</button>
        <script src="validarRUT.js"></script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: si pero lo que gustaría es que ponga el guion solo, no que tenga que escribirlo sino que automáticamente luego de ingresar el primer numero  ponga un - y luego después de 4, porque si yo en la función le permito guiones puedo escribir guiones donde sea y la idea es que solo después de 1 y luego de 4 espero explicarme bien y no se si esto sea posible con un php o un javascript y muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @JEFFmeza espero ayudar a tu inconveniente con la edición que le hice a mi respuesta